# Screen went pink

Tags: display, lcd

I've got an LCD display plugged to my PCI-e card (GeForce 7600GT), using VGA cable. At some point, after unplugging and plugging it back (I'm also using it with xbox), the display went pink. I can see everything, but it's all pink. I tried different VGA cables and monitors. DVI plug on the same card works fine, so I can use converter, but I am going to buy another monitor and I would prefer to avoid buying a new card. Is there anything I can do? Or replacing the card is the only solution?

Comment: If the DVI port works fine, then there is no problem with your video card itself, maybe the VGA port got damaged.

Answer (score 7):

When an Analog display is showing Magenta Yellow or Cyan for white, or other strange missing colors, it usually means that One Pin of the 3 RGB colors is not connected.  Unlike a data stream for DVI and HDMI, the analog VGA is 3 analog signals Red Green and Blue. Chances are good that the Green connection is not being made.  Could be a broken cable, bent pin, or just a loose cable.  A bent or broken pin or disconnection could exist in or from/to the adapter itself also.

Answer (score 2):

Some LCD display internal power supply faults can result in an overall red tint. Driving the display from something else (another PC or a laptop) may give a clue here as to whether it's a signal issue or not. Also try going into the display's setup menus - if they are pinkish too the fault is inside the display.